# Null pointer exception while starting of corda node

Tags: corda

I'm an newbie in corda and while starting the nodes using `call` command after the successful build, one of the nodes of corda throws us this null pointer exception shown below

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase$ClassEntry.equals(MethodDatabase.java:557)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.recordSuspendableMethods(MethodDatabase.java:265)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkClass(MethodDatabase.java:327)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.getOrLoadClassEntry(MethodDatabase.java:183)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.SimpleSuspendableClassifier.isSuspendable(SimpleSuspendableClassifier.java:156)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.DefaultSuspendableClassifier.isSuspendable(DefaultSuspendableClassifier.java:47)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.CheckInstrumentationVisitor.visitMethod(CheckInstrumentationVisitor.java:130)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkFileAndClose(MethodDatabase.java:347)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkClass(MethodDatabase.java:324)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.getOrLoadClassEntry(MethodDatabase.java:183)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.isMethodSuspendable0(MethodDatabase.java:194)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.isMethodSuspendable(MethodDatabase.java:161)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.InstrumentMethod.isSuspendableCall(InstrumentMethod.java:231)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.LabelSuspendableCallSitesClassVisitor$1.visitMethodInsn(LabelSuspendableCallSitesClassVisitor.java:64)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:123)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:94)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.JavaAgent$Transformer.transform(JavaAgent.java:209)
>           at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown
>   Source) [quasar] ERROR: java/lang/Thread
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase$ClassEntry.equals(MethodDatabase.java:557)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.recordSuspendableMethods(MethodDatabase.java:265)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkClass(MethodDatabase.java:327)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.getOrLoadClassEntry(MethodDatabase.java:183)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.SimpleSuspendableClassifier.isSuspendable(SimpleSuspendableClassifier.java:156)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.DefaultSuspendableClassifier.isSuspendable(DefaultSuspendableClassifier.java:47)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.CheckInstrumentationVisitor.visitMethod(CheckInstrumentationVisitor.java:130)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkFileAndClose(MethodDatabase.java:347)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkClass(MethodDatabase.java:324)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.getOrLoadClassEntry(MethodDatabase.java:183)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.isMethodSuspendable0(MethodDatabase.java:194)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.isMethodSuspendable(MethodDatabase.java:161)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.InstrumentMethod.isSuspendableCall(InstrumentMethod.java:231)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.LabelSuspendableCallSitesClassVisitor$1.visitMethodInsn(LabelSuspendableCallSitesClassVisitor.java:64)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:123)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:94)
>           at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.JavaAgent$Transformer.transform(JavaAgent.java:209)
>           at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown
>   Source)

and after a brief period of time, the node completes shows it's usual corda logo and followed by H2 console url , as an normal node. is it an normal behaviour?

I did my programming using kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

It can be

1. `call` function was not annotated with `@Suspendable`
2. One of your function that does some `send`/`receive`/`subFlow` which also calls send/receives was not annotated with `@Suspendable`

Comment: https://ideone.com/PTHKZm It's my flow code. can you have a look over it and tell me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have missed a `@Suspendable` annotation on or have included a lambda inside a function that needs to be suspended.

Comment: https://ideone.com/PTHKZm It's my flow code. can you have a look over it and tell me where I went wrong. Apparently I did not miss any `@Suspendable` in my code

Comment: ```val txCommand = Command(IOUContract.Commands.Create(), iouState.participants.map { it.owningKey })``` Maybe try move that lambda to a separate function. My other comment is what is the need to put the classes inside an object, not sure if that would cause any sort of issues. Otherwise I'm not sure whats wrong and first glance.